# Blank columns in csv file cannot be seen in sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I am creating a csv file in Excel, adding some blank columns to match the schema and while I can see them when open excel, or I can see them when open via notepad, when I upload this file to sharepoint, them see to not being available via "Open in app" option. Is it expected behaviour and they're there but on in the display?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience in Sharepoint, CSV files can be opened through the Excel desktop app and the web app.
[image: Image proof]

I would recommend checking the file extension. Otherwise, I would need you provide details of the file structure to check if there is another issue that needs to be addressed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: To be honest I don't know why it didn't work whole morning and then started to work. Looked like it has some delay. Thanks!